# Safely updating packages on Centos and custom compiled applications

Tags: linux, centos, compiling, upgrade

I've inherited some Centos servers (6.2) that I want to get up to date, we have one dev machine. I'm starting off on the dev machine going through updates with security amendments, and applying ones that look most critical first (feel free to shout if there's any recommended sites or processes to follow relating to this).

Most look straightforward, but then there's kernel packages and glibc ones.

We have quite a lot of custom compiled software. If we updated packages like the kernel and glibc ones, would the custom compiled software (things like apache, perl) carry on to work as is, or would they need to be recompiled again ?

I'm assuming things like kernel package updates would need a reboot ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minor versions like 6.2, 6.3 etc. are designed to be compatible after update (i.e. as long as 6.2 stays 6.2, and upgrades are made within it).  Most importantly, kernel major and minor versions as well as glibc major and minor versions will stay the same.  Any updates to these will not mean you need to re-compile applications.

You would need to re-compile kernel modules and such if you had them, after a kernel upgrade.  Most people do not compile their own kernel modules.

If you upgrade from 6.2 to 6.6, however, it may mean trouble.

Since it is very easy to do backups it may be worth switching one system, doing tests, then be able to switch back.